# Highcharts: Drilldown from map to chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, drilldown

Please consider `Kuwait` map:

[Kuwait Map](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/kw/kw-all)

I want when a user clicked on one state (for example - Al Jahrah) then a column chart appears for Al Jahrah series. For example:

```
Category For: Al Jahrah            Value For: Al Jahrah 
--------------------------------------------------------
Cat1                               10
Cat2                               12
Cat3                               3
```

I searched via the internet but I only saw country drill down to states. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two functions that will be responsible for creating a different type of chart and call them in the right event:

```
function mapChart() {
    Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
        chart: {
            map: 'countries/kw/kw-all'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/kw/kw-all.js">Kuwait</a>'
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 0
        },

        series: [{
            data: data,
            name: 'Random data',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        columnChart(this.name);
                        document.getElementById("back").style.display = "block"
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }]
    });

    document.getElementById("back").style.display = "none";
}

function columnChart(name) {
    var data = [1, 2, 3];

    if (name === "Al Jahrah") {
        data = [2, 2, 2];
    }

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: {
            text: name
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            data: data
        }]
    });
}

mapChart();
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bnsjgt4z/

Below you can find another solutions with drilldown from map to chart:

https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/rich-info

https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/data-class-two-ranges